# Checking for array or single instance method argument

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a method defined like this:

```
export function validation(o:Array<any> | any): void {
  if (Array.isArray(o)) {
  ...
  }
  else {
  ...
  }
```

Does typescript have a clever way to avoid the `Array.isArray` check (Something like type guards)?

Comment: `isArray` is a type guard function. From `lib.d.ts`: `isArray(arg: any): arg is Array<any>;`

Comment: Will that shorten the code or is it essentially the same?

Comment: It is already your code. The `isArray` you use is already a type guard, and is the best way to perform this check. If you need to test for a more specific array type (eg, `number[]` or `Customer[]`) you will need a custom type gurd buy for `any[]`, `isArray` is fine

Comment: OK - Perfect - Thanks!

Comment: @Titian - I deleted the other post about the word continue ... but the problem is that the constructor does not like it when the variable continue is assigned within the constructor:

Comment: class stuff {
  stop: boolean;
  constructor(continue: boolean) {
    this.continue = continue;
  }
}

Comment: Could probably use another variable name though ...

Comment: Yup. `continue` does not appear to be valid for parameter names, but my guess it's not in JS either

Comment: Yup, checked it's a JS error to declare a parameter named continue.